# Command not properly ended with subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do this: 
Create a view that will display the concatenated name, JobTitle and Salary of the people who have a Cat value of Y and whose salary is at least 25 percent higher than the average salary of all people who have a Cat value of Y. The three column headings should be Name, JobTitle and Salary. The rows should be sorted in traditional phonebook order.

and this is what i've entered:

```
CREATE VIEW A11T1 AS 
SELECT initcap(FNAME) ||' '|| initcap(LNAME) as Name, 
initcap(JobTitle) as JobTitle, Salary
FROM PERSON11 
    (select avg(salary) as averagesalary
     from PERSON11
     Where upper(cat) = 'Y')    
WHERE salary >= (1.25 * averagesalary)
Order by InitCap(Lname), InitCap(Fname)
```

I am getting this error:

> SQL command not properly ended

Any help with this would be great. :)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, your `from` clause needs a `join`:

```
SELECT ( initcap(FNAME) ||' '|| initcap(LNAME) ) as Name,
       initcap(JobTitle) as JobTitle, Salary
FROM PERSON11 CROSS JOIN
     (select avg(salary) as averagesalary
      from PERSON11
      Where upper(cat) = 'Y'
     ) x
WHERE salary >= (1.25 * x.averagesalary)
ORDER BY InitCap(Lname), InitCap(Fname);
```

Comment: why would I need to join information that is already in the same table?

Comment: @TJ.Anderson . . . You are asking what is wrong with your query.  That is what I'm answering.

Comment: @TJAnderson - `averagesalary` is not in "the same table" - it's generated as the result of a SELECT statement, which logically defines a different table. In order to explain how this works, should your instructor ask, you might want to look up what a CROSS JOIN does if you're not familiar with it. Best.

Answer (score 0):

He only has to add a comma after the first table and lose the order by. The rest is ok.